# GetText function in Webview2 in a .net framework WPF application

Tags: wpf, webview2

I've recently been trying out editors like an ace editor on **Webview2**, since **cefsharp** is very power-hungry. My problem is that I seem to not find a single way as to how to get the text inside the editor with C# code, there seem to be no functions included, and I've been researching for about a day now and I have not found any results.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the ace api, pretty sure it has a GetText function.
Edit,

You can use a function like this to get the text and print it to a textbox:

```
// Note to you idk.xyz, use sx.Execute(EditorText);
String EditorText = Json.Decode(await 
Editor.ExecuteScriptAsync("GetText();"));
// The line below just proves that it gets the text in the ace editor.
aaaa.Text = EditorText;
```

I will link a project also that has an example in it:
https://anonfiles.com/f7z9Lby3u6/testts_rar

Edit: Thanks for upvote ❤